# azure deploy eventSubscription failed since servicebus's requireSession is true

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I met a deployment failure when I deploy eventSubscription which Topic type is EventGrid and endpoint Type is ServiceBus queue. I set the service bus' requireSession property be true and found eventSubscription deployment will fail. Here is error message:
"code":"InvalidSessionQueueWithoutSessionIdAttributeCategory","message":"Can't add resource /subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/xx/queues/testqueue as a destination without including SessionId as a Delivery Property because the Service Bus queue has session support enabled.

But if I set requireSession false for serviceBus, the deploy would succeed.

I would like to know if any doc states serviceBus requireSession can't be true if has subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-service-bus#service-bus-queues

"Session enabled queues are not supported as event handlers for Azure Event Grid events"

Answer (score 1):

[Delivery Properties ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5HSu.png)

One can integrate eventgrid with Service Bus(that has sessions enabled) by passing sessionId in Delivery Properties. While creating event subscription in the portal, session id has to be specified in the delivery properties section. With this change, it should work fine